how to prove that a given structure is a model of a given theory?
Suppose we have a particular logical theory and a particular structure. What are the methods to prove that this given structure is indeed a model for that given theory? Is it just sufficient to prove that axioms of a theory are satisfied in the structure? Or we need to prove more than that? I assume the answer would be different for the 1st and 2nd order theories but it would be interesting to know the answer for both cases.

Yes, show that the axioms are satisfied by the given structure.

A model for a theory (a collection of sentences) is a structure that satisfies the axioms of the theory.
Thus, to show that structure $\mathfrak A$ is a model for theory $T$, in symbols $\mathfrak A \vDash T$, we have to check that the axioms of $T$ are satisfied by $\mathfrak A$.
The general definition applies also to Second-Order Logic.
